# pow() does not work with variable exponent 1/N (Nth root)

Tags: pine-script

pow(M,1/N) always gives "1", no matter the value of M or N

Is there another expression/way to take the Nth root of M?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exponent should be a float, try using `pow(M,1./N)`.